# What is the execution order of the lines inside a method- Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

What is the chronology of executing lines inside a method in Kotlin?

```
    fun main()
{
    testExecutionOrder()
}

fun testExecutionOrder()
{
    for (item in 1..2)
    {
        print("hey, how are you?")
        loopingInfinitely()

    }
}

fun loopingInfinitely()
{
    while(true)
    {
        print("I am fine.")
       
    }
}
```

I am expecting it to give output like;

```
//hey, how are you?  I am fine. I am fine....(infinitely)
```

But the output is something like following;

```
// am fine. I am fine. I am fine. I am fine. I am fine. (Infinitely)
```

Why is it excluding 'I' while printing the first time and why is it not printing "hey, how are you?" at all.

Here is the original console output:
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't trust the console output if an infitite loop is in play. You can see that the execution order is as you expect if you simply remove the infinite loop and keep the `print("I am fine")`. The inifinite loop fills your console until its limit is reached. The "hey, how are you?" is instantly overwritten before you can even see it.

Comment: If you ran this on the command line, and press ctrl-c, and you scrolled up to the command invocation, you can notice that for sure, "how are you" was printed once.

Comment: The content has just been cut since the console output is limited. Everything is run sequentially in Java (Kotlin), unless you specify that you want asynchronous calls. There you will have a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

well, your output is in fact like you are expecting, starts with "hey, how are you?", then printing "I am fine." again and again

there is a limit of capacity in log and you are printing "im fine" so often (`while(true)`) that text exceeds text size limit in split second and beggining of printed text ("how are you?") get lost

if you are using Android framework then you should use logcat and `Log.i()` method. you will notice that your code is printing new "im fine" line probably multiple times in one milisecond, thats too much text for showing in console/logcat window

Comment: could probably just step through this with breakpoints as well, right ?

Comment: That is understandable but doesn't the console uses queue property for printing the output?

Comment: @AkashKumarRoy What is a "queue property"? The console is just that: a sink that data is written to sequentially. If you send too much data, too fast, it overruns, and the initial entries get thrown away.

Comment: probably is using some queueing/buffering, but still you are posting so much text with every milisec that console output window won't handle such amount (thus is limited). change your `while(true)` to some other condition, e.g. 1..5 iteration and whole console output will be there, also with first line. still, consider using `Log` and logcat tab in Android Studio, you will get additional precise time of every logged line, this will reveal hom much/many/often this text is printed

Comment: Maybe that can be a reason. The output made me think that maybe inside the method the other method is being called first before even executing print. So that is for sure not the concept, right?

Comment: right, in posted code every method is called sequentially and there is no option that any other method gets called in the meanwhile (in same thread)